# word tables extracting to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract tables from word app to Excel,i write a program to do that and it works. now i want to generalize this program (in case i have n tables) using loops, please if have any idea about how, i'll be so thankful.

```
**Sub FF()
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim Fichier As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Fichier = "C:\Users\Desktop\ME\ME1.docx"
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = False 
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Fichier)
j = 1
    WordDoc.Tables(1).Range.Copy
    Cells(j, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
j = 20
    WordDoc.Tables(2).Range.Copy
    Cells(j, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
WordDoc.Close False
WordApp.Quit
End Sub**
```

Comment: `For Each wdTable In WordDoc.Tables` should loop through them.

Comment: thank you @braX for your comment, but i think that this loop will past all tables in the same range(for that i used in my program j=1 and j=20, i did that to have all my tables one under the other)

Comment: You can count how many rows each table has, and increment your other variables accordingly... `wdTable.Rows.Count` using my loop code.

Comment: You could also create a new sheet in the workbook for each table, which might be easier.

Comment: please can you explain more how to use wdTables.Rows.Count

Comment: for the other proposition,i cant because i have to range all my tables (about 100 table) in one sheet

Comment: Can you please explain to me: CurrentRow = CurrentRow + T.Rows.Count + 1 !!

Comment: `CurrentRow` is a variable I am using to track where the next table will start.

Comment: it realy works, thank you, but it doesnt past the 2nd table (it pasted 3 columns instead of 4 columns)

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but it demonstrates what I mean from the above comments.

```
Dim CurrentRow As Long
CurrentRow = 1

For Each wdTable In WordDoc.Tables
    wdTable.Range.Copy
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Select
        .Paste
    End With
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + wdTable.Rows.Count + 1
Next
```

Comment: it realy works, thank you, but it doesnt past the 2nd table (it pasted 3 columns instead of 4 columns)